# check javascript array value is not empty

Tags: javascript, json

I am a little confused with checking if an array value us empty from a json response.

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "message": "All pages re-ordered",
  "content": {
    "_wysihtml5_mode": "1",
    "Page": {
        "title": "cover",
        "page_text": "dfvdfvdfvdfvdv story go daddy xxx",
        "storyborad_img": "1jhkjh.png",
        "background_url": "kjbj.png",
        "newBackground_url": "",
        "text_font": "arial",
        "id": "30",
        "book_id": "38",
        "newStoryborad_img": {
            "name": "1jhkjh.png",
            "type": "image\/png",
            "tmp_name": "\/Applications\/MAMP\/tmp\/php\/phpvyf8Xx",
            "error": 0,
            "size": 185607
        }
    },
    "User": {
        "username": "testuser"
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried to check `typeof array == undefined` and `.length` but both give me what is in the else statement `newBackground_url`

```
var page = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText.replace('</p>', ''));
var imageType;
if(page.content.Page.newStoryborad_img.length > 0) {
    imageType = page.content.Page.newStoryborad_img.name;
}
else {
    imageType = page.content.Page.newBackground_url.name;
}
```

Comment: Why is there a `</p>` in your JSON? The path should be `page.content.Page.storyborad_img` [sic] according to your code.

Comment: </p> was part of the response, but I am changing it around so will remove that once I have the code refactored.

Comment: 'Storyborad' reminded me of http://kazakhstana.files.wordpress.com/2011/09/borat-swimsuit.jpg

Comment: Isn't `newStoryborad_img` an object? Or, do you receive an `array` when there are more than one images?

Comment: `typeof(array) == undefined` *should* give you the else statement, because you have defined it in your json.  You might want `typeof(array) != 'undefined'` if you want its presence to trigger the `if` block.  (which is what it looks like you want it to do)

Comment: I am a little green with the terminology, yes I parse the json into array/object called page. Sorry not sure which

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.  According to your example, you are returning an object `"newStoryborad_img": {...}`

In which case you would want to use `typeof(page.content.Page.newStoryborad_img) != 'undefined'`

Demo typeof: http://jsfiddle.net/gunderjt/cn2cs/

But if you are looking at having an *array* of objects `"newStoryborad_img": [{...}]` (notice the brackets).  Then to check the presence of any objects in the array (assuming you are returning an empty array)

`page.content.Page.newStoryborad_img.length > 0` will be what you want

Demo length: http://jsfiddle.net/gunderjt/cn2cs/1/

Comment: thanks for the help. If I change "newStoryborad_img": "" I get if instead of else for the typeof. I will always be passing newStoryborad_img either empty or with values

Comment: @KeithPower, and this is an update to @JTG's answer/fiddle, change the if statement condition to `typeof(page.content.Page.newStoryborad_img) != 'string'` meaning it's an object or anything else that is not a string, then console.log if. If it's a string i.e. "", then console.log else. [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cn2cs/2/)